# To get a page with wget once it has loaded or gone ready

Tags: curl, wget

I am not quite sure, how to put this question aptly.

I am trying to get the HTML content of pages of the form http://www.youtube-mp3.org/#v=9MzikThwfPE.
If I open it in browser I have to wait for the youtube video that corresponds to the youtube id [-> here is v=9MzikThwfPE] to be converted to mp3 and then a link to download appears.
What I am trying to do is to get the HTML content of the webpage when this download link exists or is visible.
If I just try to get the page with wget I dont get the content, that I will once the video is processed.
How can I do this with wget or curl?
Thank you.

Comment: The page uses JavaScript to construct the page dynamically, curl and wget do not process JS. Check whether the site provides an API for what you want.

Comment: Well! the page doesn't provide any API. Oh! ok so you mean to say there is no way to do this with wget?

Comment: Because the download link isn't in the HTML. It's added to the DOM using Javascript. Perhaps they did it this way to prevent people from doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org).

As @Barmar mentioned it is not possible to get a dynamically generated HTML content with wget or curl as they don't support js or doesn't have a support for a js engine.

phantomjs on the other hand has support for js and can behave like a browser, we can post requests, store cookies and also many other things that you can do with java supported browser.
Here is the sample js script that does the job [to host the page, get the dynamic HTML content and store cookies]

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system');

if (system.args.length < 2 || system.args.length > 2) {
    console.log('Usage: dl.js URL');
    phantom.exit(1);
}
else{ 
    var url=system.args[1];
    page.open(url,
          function (status) {
      if (status !== 'success') {
          console.log('Unable to access network');
      } else {
          window.setTimeout(function(){
              steps = page.content;
              console.log(steps);
              phantom.exit();
          },10000);
      }
      }); 
}
```

Thank you.